# Android TextToSpeach добавить паузы в sinthesizeToFile

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Я разрабатываю спортивную программу на android. Использую textToSpeach для проговаривания упражнений через определенные интервалы времени. Подскажите, есть ли возможность сгенерировать медиа-файл с текстом, содержащим паузы определенной длительности? Есть метод synthesizeToFile, но не вижу, как можно добавить туда паузы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494130/how-to-give-pause-or-gap-between-words-in-tts-in-android

Comment: Yakov, спасибо за ссылку. Но паузы нужно не произносить, а поместить в wav или mp3-файл.

Comment: погугли, ms tts умеет начитывать из xml, возможно гугл тоже понимает хмл разметку для синтеза.

Comment: Похоже в IOS можно так сделать, а в android проблема.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349672/android-tts-in-text-controls-are-they-available-or-any-equivalent-technique